# Holomorphic extension of an action by a compact Lie group on a complex homogeneous manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $M$ be a $G$-homogeneous manifold. Suppose that $M$ is endowed with a complex structure invariant by the action of $G$. Denote by $G_{\mathbb C}$ the complexification of $G$.

Are there known conditions so that the action of $G$ on $M$ can be extended to a holomorphic action of $G_{\mathbb C}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work for a connected group $G$. The Lie algebra action extends, by multiplying by $J$, to a complex Lie algebra action. By compactness of $M$, these vector fields are all complete. So some covering group of the complexification acts, for example the universal covering group $\tilde{G}_{\mathbb{C}}$ acts. Hochschild, **The Structure of Complex Lie Groups**, chapter XVII, §5, proves that if $G$ admits a faithful finite dimensional representation, then $G$ injects into its complexification. For example, all compact Lie groups admit faithful finite dimensional representations. The group $G$ is then the maximal compact subgroup of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$; Broecker and tom Dieck, Representations of Compact Lie Groups, p. 153, prop. 8.3. Every connected Lie group retracts to its maximal compact subgroup. In particular, the fundamental group of $G$ and of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ are the same, represented by loops in $G$.
The fundamental group of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ embeds into the universal covering group $\tilde{G}_{\mathbb{C}}$. We need to see which elements of it act trivially, so that we can see which quotient of $\tilde{G}_{\mathbb{C}}$ the action descends to. The fundamental group of the original compact group sits as a subgroup of $\tilde{G}$, but acts trivially on $M$. So the same is true for the fundamental group of $G_{\mathbb{C}}$: $\pi_1(G_{\mathbb{C}}) \subset \tilde{G}_{\mathbb{C}}$ acts trivially on $M$. Hence $G_{\mathbb{C}}$ acts on the complex homogeneous space $M$.

Comment: You are assuming that $M$ is compact, which is reasonable -- otherwise this is clearly false, the Poincaré upper half-space being an obvious counter-example.

Comment: @abx: The problem has $M$ a $G$-homogeneous space, so $M$ admits a transitive action of a compact Lie group, so is compact.

Comment: Oops! Of course, sorry.

Comment: @BenMcKay: It seems to me that your argument gives a complex Lie group $H$ ( i.e. generated by all the flows of the complex Lie algebra ) of diffeomorphisms of $M$ which contains the original $G$. So by the universal property (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification_(Lie_group)) the complexification $G_C$ covers $H$ hence acts on $M$  perhaps not faithful, but the OP do not ask for a faitful action.   Thus your argument solves the question, isn't it?

Comment: @Holonomia: yes, I think so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @BenMcKay.

Is the first extension due to Palais theorem? If so, I understand why you are using that the vector fields are all complete.

If I'm not mistaken, the Lie algebra action you are considering is, for $X + iY \in \mathfrak g + i \mathfrak g$  you associate the smooth vector field on $M$ given by $\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} (\exp(tX)m) + i \frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} (\exp(tY)m)$ for each $m \in M$.

But the version of the theorem I known use the flow on M to construct the action, but the flow only exist for real vector fields. Is there a complex version of theorem?

Comment: @MaxReinholJahnke: I should have said that you use $J$ rather than $i$, the almost complex structure induced by the complex structure. Then you get a $J$-invariant collection of real vector fields. You then use $J$ as the complex structure on that Lie algebra of vector fields.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are suggesting that I consider the Lie algebra action $X + iY \in \mathfrak g + i \mathfrak g \mapsto \frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} (\exp(tX)m) +  J\left(\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} (\exp(t Y)m)\right)$?

Comment: @MaxReinholJahnke: No. The action is $X+iY \in \mathfrak{g} + i \mathfrak{g} \mapsto \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \exp(t(X+JY)m).$.

Comment: Dear @BenMcKay, I'm having a hard time understanding your answer. I understand that you use Palais' theorem to extend the action to a covering of the complexified group, but what guarantee that you can define it on the complexification? Can you be more specific on what results you are using or indicate some references? Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @Max Reinhol Jahnke: you have to regard the Lie algebra of the group $G$ as a finite dimensional Lie algebra of vector fields of $M$. If  $X_1,\cdots,X_k$ are generators of such Lie algebra then consider the vector fields $JX_1, \cdots JX_k$. Then the 2k vectors fields $X_1,\cdots,X_k, JX_1,\cdots,JX_k$ generates a finite dimensional complex Lie algebra. By Palais theorem,using flow completeness, you have that a complex Lie group $H$ acts on $M$. Then by the universal property of the complexification (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification_(Lie_group)) you get that $G_C$ acts on $M$.